# Docker virtual network interfaces are mandatory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

Docker fill my network manager with many network interfaces that i think are unnecessary.

[image: unnecessary network interfaces]

My simply project have 4 container and 1 network.

Why i need this long list of network interfaces?

I expect to have just a single networks interfaces for every project, not for every container. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each container lives in it's own name space, seperate and cut off from the host and other containers. If you run 5 containers, by default you will have 5 veth interfaces so each container can communicate outside it's own name space.

The Docker "network" creates 1 bridge, which all the veth interfaces are connected to.

If you don't need IP communication from a container you can run it with `--net=none`.

You could also share/mount a socket file between containers to allow unix socket communication without the interface.